# Could "Diagnostic" be used as a noun and in plural form?

Tags: word-usage

I've noticed that "*Diagnostic*" can be used as a plural! Such as in some windows warning messages. What's the subtle difference between **Diagnostic** and **Diagnosis**? How do we use each of them in a correct way?

Comment: [The exact same question was asked previously](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600955/do-you-call-this-a-device-diagnostic-or-device-diagnosis) but closed for having no research (!) There's [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301097/which-one-is-common-diagnostic-or-diagnostics) on singular v plural. And several others on the word "diagnostic/diagnostics" if you maybe search ELL SE.

Comment: Compare the plural ending with the adjective to create a noun:  **haptic**, **haptics**;  **bionic**, **bionics**; **dialectic**, **dialectics**; **kinetic**, **kinetics**; **genetic**, **genetics**; **linguistic**, **linguistics**; **therapeutic**,**therapeutics**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ***diagnostics*** is often used. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnostic) defines *diagnostic* as:

> the art or practice of diagnosis —**often used in plural**

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diagnostic) has this definition for ***diagnostics***, which a term also used in IT:

> methods or systems for discovering the cause of a problem, illness, etc.
>
> - Requests for off-site testing and ***diagnostics*** are frequently ignored or refused without explanation.

The most thorough explanation is given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/diagnostic):

> *diagnostic*
> [usually pl., with sing. v.]
>
> - the art, science, or method of diagnosis, esp. medical diagnosis
> - a distinguishing sign or symptom; characteristic
> - Computing 
>    a routine for testing a piece of hardware or for locating an error in a program

The difference between ***diagnostics*** and ***diagnosis*** in medicine is that:

> ***Diagnostics*** provide a cluster of ***objective measures directed toward identifying the cause of a disease***... ***Diagnosis***, by contrast, ***rests on a patient’s history and symptoms and observed physical and laboratory findings***.([NLibMedicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK57026/))

More concretely,

> ***Diagnosis*** is defined as ***the process of recognising an injury, condition, or disease from the signs and symptoms the individual is displaying***. Diagnostic tests are used to ascertain a diagnosis. Blood tests, health history, physical assessments, and other procedures may be used to help make a diagnosis. ***Diagnostics*** include using ***testing and other procedures to arrive at a diagnosis for a particular disease or illness***. ([Talking Health Tech](https://www.talkinghealthtech.com/glossary/diagnostics-versus-diagnosis#:%7E:text=Diagnosis%20is%20defined%20as%20the,to%20help%20make%20a%20diagnosis.))

So while the *diagnosis* is the actual identifying of the problem or disease, *diagnostics* are the methods used to make that identification, or the art of doing it (the field).

Here is a definition of IT diagnostics by [Easy Tech Junkie](https://www.easytechjunkie.com/what-are-computer-diagnostics.htm):

> **Computer** ***diagnostics*** are software programs designed to scan the hard disk and other computer hardware components of a computer system, and identify any issues that may be hampering the overall performance of that system.